# Make a new dictionary that have no None items in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
stocks= {'AALI': {'company': 'Astra Agro Lestari Tbk.'},
 'ABBA': {'company': 'Mahaka Media Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
 'ABDA': {'company': 'Asuransi Bina Dana Arta Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'ABMM': {'company': 'ABM Investama Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
 'ACES': {'company': 'Ace Hardware Indonesia Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'ACST': {'company': 'Acset Indonusa Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'ADES': {'company': 'Akasha Wira International Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'ADHI': {'company': 'Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'ADMF': {'company': 'Adira Dinamika Multi Finance T', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
 'ADMG': {'company': 'Polychem Indonesia Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'ADRO': {'company': 'Adaro Energy Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
 'AGAR': {'company': 'Asia Sejahtera Mina Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'AGII': {'company': 'Aneka Gas Industri Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'AGRO': {'company': 'Bank Raya Indonesia Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'AGRS': {'company': 'Bank IBK Indonesia Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
 'AHAP': {'company': 'Asuransi Harta Aman Pratama Tb', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'AIMS': {'company': 'Akbar Indo Makmur Stimec Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'AISA': {'company': 'FKS Food Sejahtera Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'AKKU': {'company': 'Anugerah Kagum Karya Utama Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
 'AKPI': {'company': 'Argha Karya Prima Industry Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': None},
 'AKRA': {'company': 'AKR Corporindo Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None}}
```

I want to make a new dictionary that only consist of the stocks that have value in the 'CDLDOJI', I want to remove all the stocks that is None in the new dictionary. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dictionary comprehension that does that.

```
stocks = {
    'AALI': {'company': 'Astra Agro Lestari Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'ABBA': {'company': 'Mahaka Media Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
    'ABDA': {'company': 'Asuransi Bina Dana Arta Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'ABMM': {'company': 'ABM Investama Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
    'ACES': {'company': 'Ace Hardware Indonesia Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'ACST': {'company': 'Acset Indonusa Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'ADES': {'company': 'Akasha Wira International Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'ADHI': {'company': 'Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'ADMF': {'company': 'Adira Dinamika Multi Finance T', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
    'ADMG': {'company': 'Polychem Indonesia Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'ADRO': {'company': 'Adaro Energy Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
    'AGAR': {'company': 'Asia Sejahtera Mina Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'AGII': {'company': 'Aneka Gas Industri Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'AGRO': {'company': 'Bank Raya Indonesia Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'AGRS': {'company': 'Bank IBK Indonesia Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
    'AHAP': {'company': 'Asuransi Harta Aman Pratama Tb', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'AIMS': {'company': 'Akbar Indo Makmur Stimec Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'AISA': {'company': 'FKS Food Sejahtera Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'AKKU': {'company': 'Anugerah Kagum Karya Utama Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': 'bullish'},
    'AKPI': {'company': 'Argha Karya Prima Industry Tbk', 'CDLDOJI': None},
    'AKRA': {'company': 'AKR Corporindo Tbk.', 'CDLDOJI': None}
}

stocks = {k: v for k, v in stocks.items() if v.get("CDLDOJI") is not None}
```

Printing the new `stocks` yields

```
{
    'ABBA': {'CDLDOJI': 'bullish', 'company': 'Mahaka Media Tbk.'},
    'ABMM': {'CDLDOJI': 'bullish', 'company': 'ABM Investama Tbk.'},
    'ADMF': {'CDLDOJI': 'bullish', 'company': 'Adira Dinamika Multi Finance T'},
    'ADRO': {'CDLDOJI': 'bullish', 'company': 'Adaro Energy Tbk.'},
    'AGRS': {'CDLDOJI': 'bullish', 'company': 'Bank IBK Indonesia Tbk.'},
    'AKKU': {'CDLDOJI': 'bullish', 'company': 'Anugerah Kagum Karya Utama Tbk'}
}
```

Comment: what if i want to add an else in the {}? so if v doesnt have a ["CDLDOJI"] attribute, just pass.

Comment: @Saran I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: i've updated the stocks dictionary in my question